# Task does not complete if another task with in it gets cancelled

Tags: c#, task

In this code, the task `t` will never complete (never outputs to the console) if I cancel the token, even though the token is not used for `t` and only used for a task inside `t`

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000, token);
    Console.WriteLine("Task Completed");
});

source.Cancel();
```

How can I cancel the token but also let the task complete

Notes:
I tried using `Task.Run` instead, and got the same output
`t.IsCompleted` will stay false indefinitely (task will never complete)
The delay task does complete

Comment: Are you sure that the `t` will not complete? I would expect it to complete in a `Faulted` state, with the `IsCompleted` being true and the `IsCompletedSuccessfully` being false. You could try adding `t.Wait()` after the `source.Cancel()`, and see what happens.

Comment: Seems to complete as you said, when I debugged it, I used a `Console.WriteLine` after the `source.Cancel()` but it seems like it needs a bit of time to update. Even if it completes why is it `Faulted` and how can I make it complete successfully?

Edit: forgot to answer the second part of your comment, it didn't help everything stayed the same, I dont think `Wait()` does anything if the task is already completed

Comment: Actually the `t.Wait()` will not help at surfacing the exception, because of the known problem of assigning a `Task.Factory.StartNew(async` to a `Task` instead of a `Task<Task>`. For more info about this you could take a look here: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `t` to survive the cancellation, by handling and suppressing the [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception) that is thrown by the `Task.Delay`:

```
Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try { await Task.Delay(1000, token); } catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    Console.WriteLine("Task Completed");
});
```

Comment: Seems to work, I didn't know that cancelling would actually throw an exception. Thank you